# Bizdays function returning incorrect values

Tags: r, date, datetime

I am trying to calculate the number of business days between two dates using the package `bizdays`.  There have been many posts on the fact that it is a good option to use to calculate business days between two dates, but no posts on specific issues while using it.  I am currently having an issue with the output.

I have data with differences between dates ranging from seconds to months, but below in my sample df, I will only show the differences that are less than a day (these are where the issue seems to arise).

Here is my df:

```
Transition_Dates <- data.frame(Enter = as.POSIXct(c("2015-06-28 19:48:00",
                                             "2015-06-14 04:05:00",
                                             "2013-11-21 04:56:59",
                                             "2016-01-16 11:18:00",
                                             "2015-12-19 14:02:59")), 
                        Exit = as.POSIXct(c("2015-06-28 19:48:59",
                                            "2015-06-14 04:06:59",
                                            "2013-11-21 10:24:00",
                                            "2016-01-18 06:21:00",
                                            "2015-12-19 14:11:00")),
                        Time_in_State = c(0.00, 0.00, 0.23, 1.79, 0.01))
```

As you can see, there is a third column that has a calculation WITHOUT removing non-business days (good to compare below to the `bizdays` output).

Here is my `bizdays` calendar:

```
library(bizdays)
library(lubridate)
Non_Working_Calendar <- Calendar(holidays = as.Date(c("2013-07-04", "2013-09-02", "2013-10-14", "2013-11-11", "2013-11-21", "2013-11-22", as.character(seq(ymd("2013-12-24"), ymd("2014-01-01"), "days")), 
                                          "2014-01-20", "2014-02-17", "2014-05-26", "2014-07-04", "2014-09-01", "2014-10-13", "2014-11-11", "2014-11-27", "2014-11-28", as.character(seq(ymd("2014-12-24"), ymd("2015-01-01"), "days")),
                                          "2015-01-19", "2015-02-16", "2015-05-25", "2015-07-03", "2015-09-07", "2015-10-12", "2015-11-11", "2015-11-26", "2015-11-27", as.character(seq(ymd("2015-12-24"), ymd("2016-01-01"), "days")),
                                          "2016-01-18", "2016-02-15", "2016-05-30", "2016-07-04", "2016-09-05", "2016-10-10", "2016-11-11", "2016-11-24", "2016-11-25", as.character(seq(ymd("2016-12-24"), ymd("2017-01-01"), "days")),
                                          "2017-01-16", "2017-02-20", "2017-05-29", "2017-07-04", "2017-09-04", "2017-10-09", "2017-11-10", "2017-11-23", "2017-11-24", as.character(seq(ymd("2016-12-24"), ymd("2017-01-01"), "days")))), start.date = as.Date("2010-01-01"), end.date = as.Date("2020-01-01"), weekdays = c("saturday", "sunday"))
bizdays.options$set(default.calendar = Non_Working_Calendar)
```

Add `bizdays` output to df:

```
Transition_Dates$bdays <- bizdays(Transition_Dates$Enter, Transition_Dates$Exit)
Transition_Dates
                Enter                Exit Time_in_State bdays
1 2015-06-28 19:48:00 2015-06-28 19:48:59          0.00    -1
2 2015-06-14 04:05:00 2015-06-14 04:06:59          0.00    -1
3 2013-11-21 04:56:59 2013-11-21 10:24:00          0.23    -1
4 2016-01-16 11:18:00 2016-01-18 06:21:00          1.79    -1
5 2015-12-19 14:02:59 2015-12-19 14:11:00          0.01    -1
```

Has anyone come across a similar issue or am I totally missing something?  For the majority of the observations, the `bdays` column correctly rounds up or down from the `Time_in_State` column, but I haven't figured out why it would give me -1 for some of these.  Also, is there a way to have `bizdays` output with decimals (e.g., 5.5, 12.11)?  I didn't see anything in the manual.  Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm bizdays' father.
This is a BUG and I'll work on it, for now in order to get what you want I suggest the following code.

```
Transition_Dates <- data.frame(Enter = as.POSIXct(c("2015-06-28 19:48:00",
                                                "2015-06-14 04:05:00",
                                                "2013-11-21 04:56:59",
                                                "2016-01-16 11:18:00",
                                                "2015-12-19 14:02:59")), 
                           Exit = as.POSIXct(c("2015-06-28 19:48:59",
                                               "2015-06-14 04:06:59",
                                               "2013-11-21 10:24:00",
                                               "2016-01-18 06:21:00",
                                               "2015-12-19 14:11:00")),
                           Time_in_State = c(0.00, 0.00, 0.23, 1.79, 0.01))

bypass <- function(x, cal) x

library(bizdays)
library(lubridate)
Non_Working_Calendar <- Calendar(holidays=as.Date(c("2013-07-04", "2013-09-02", "2013-10-14", "2013-11-11", "2013-11-21", "2013-11-22", as.character(seq(ymd("2013-12-24"), ymd("2014-01-01"), "days")), 
                                                    "2014-01-20", "2014-02-17", "2014-05-26", "2014-07-04", "2014-09-01", "2014-10-13", "2014-11-11", "2014-11-27", "2014-11-28", as.character(seq(ymd("2014-12-24"), ymd("2015-01-01"), "days")),
                                                    "2015-01-19", "2015-02-16", "2015-05-25", "2015-07-03", "2015-09-07", "2015-10-12", "2015-11-11", "2015-11-26", "2015-11-27", as.character(seq(ymd("2015-12-24"), ymd("2016-01-01"), "days")),
                                                    "2016-01-18", "2016-02-15", "2016-05-30", "2016-07-04", "2016-09-05", "2016-10-10", "2016-11-11", "2016-11-24", "2016-11-25", as.character(seq(ymd("2016-12-24"), ymd("2017-01-01"), "days")),
                                                    "2017-01-16", "2017-02-20", "2017-05-29", "2017-07-04", "2017-09-04", "2017-10-09", "2017-11-10", "2017-11-23", "2017-11-24", as.character(seq(ymd("2016-12-24"), ymd("2017-01-01"), "days")))),
                                 start.date=as.Date("2010-01-01"),
                                 end.date = as.Date("2020-01-01"),
                                 weekdays = c("saturday", "sunday"),
                                 adjust.from=bypass,
                                 adjust.to=bypass)

bizdays.options$set(default.calendar = Non_Working_Calendar)
```

with this code I got

```
> bizdays(Transition_Dates$Enter, Transition_Dates$Exit)
[1] 0 0 0 0 0
```

That problem appears because `bizdays` default settings (adjust.from and adjust.to) intends to replicate Excel's NETWORKDAYS behaviour. Once `from` and `to` arguments are nonworking days the date adjustment causes strange results you have pointed.

```
> is.bizday(Transition_Dates$Enter)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> is.bizday(Transition_Dates$Exit)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

The function `bypass` disables the adjustment and now I have to figure out a clean way to incorporate that feature in `bizdays`.

Comment: thank you for the thoughtful reply.  I am still having an issue with some other dates as well.  Using the calendar above: `bizdays("2014-10-10 11:33:00", "2014-10-16 10:03:00")` returns 3 business days, but it should round to 4 (Friday 11:30am to Thursday 10:03am).  If I run `bizseq("2014-10-10 11:33:00", "2014-10-16 10:03:00")`, it returns a vector of 4 days.  Do you recommend that as a workaround for now?  Can I incorporate this with a vector of dates to/from?  I will try experimenting.

Comment: For now I'd suggest to add 1 to `bizdays` return. `bizdays` the difference between two dates so that if you call `bizdays("2014-10-10 11:33:00", "2014-10-11 11:33:00")` returns 1 instead of 2, but if you call `bizseq("2014-10-10 11:33:00", "2014-10-11 11:33:00")`, it returns a sequence with 2 dates. `bizdays` was designed for financial purposes and I'll think on new ways to make it more customizable for other uses.

Comment: whoops I missed Columbus Day in my comment above.  Your first answer works great.  Thanks again.